# No exit stamp after leaving the Schengen area?

Tags: schengen-visas, passport-stamps

I recently noticed that my Schengen visa wasn't stamped when I left.
Although I really left and I am now at home, my sponsor has asked me to go to the Embassy and get an exit stamp. He is now afraid to that the police will come to his home, because I am not recorded in the system as having left the country.
The Embassy said they cannot help.

What can or should I do at this point?
Will my sponsor have problems because I have no exit stamp?
Finally, will I have problems if I apply for a new visa in the future?

Comment: It is not necessarily common to stamp the visa itself when you leave the Schengen area. Are you sure that the exit stamp is not somewhere else in your passport? In any case, there is no 'system' in which your exit is registered, so there is also no risk for a missing record. Your sponsor has no reason to worry. *You* however *may* get a problem if you are going to the Schengen area in the next 6 months or so and don't have a stamp to show how long you staid the first time.

Comment: hi thanks , in fact, when i left the officer at the border was making fun with my name and he was a bit "heavy" on  me, as he was giving me compliment on my clothes ( i left germany, on traditional costume). so i guess he forgot to stamp. i am sure that there are no stamp, i can see the one on arrival, and i have never travaeled befor, so my indian passport in empty. so i just ask my sponsor, and he said that he is now very much fearing to get bothered by immigration poilce.

Comment: we chat yesterday , so he saw me sitting with my parents in bangalore, so he knows i am home, but he insist i get the stamp....what can i do

Comment: There is no way to get an exit stamp now. As you have been told, the Embassy in your country can't/won't stamp your passport.

Comment: in case i travel again ( not in the menu) maybe i will lost this passport, but it is only to reassure my sponsor. and be sure that no one is looking for my in germany, as i am in bangalore ( i will marry in 3 month)

Comment: so i should have been more carefull, next time if i travel, i will really check if i got stamped....

Comment: do NOT "lose" your passport. the passport does not actually belong to you, it belongs to your government. please don't compound one issue with another.

Comment: ok thank you, again one last question, how does the authorities know that you have departed? i ask it because, i imagine that if i dont have the exit stamp, and maybe one day i will go back, how will the autorities known that i have been honest, or overstayed 1 day or 10 years???

Comment: Just make sure you keep all documentation relating to your trip out, including ticket details, boarding pass, etc. Any other evidence that you have left the Schengen Area (hotels, trains, meals, withdrawals from ATMs, etc.) should also be kept safe. This will allow you to show you did actually leave the Schengen Area in the unlikely event someone inquires. But remember that there is currently no database of entries/exits, so nobody knows if you have left or not, and the only situation they may inquire about it is if they find you in the Schengen Area, which they obviously can't...

Comment: When you apply again for a visa, they will look for the exit stamp. You should include your proof of arrival in India when you make this application. Did you recieve an entry stamp in India or in transit to India?

Comment: Your Sponsor will **only** be contacted if, through your overstay, costs occur (for which he must pay for). But since you have left, **no costs will occur** thus immigration has no reason to contact him. You should tell him that.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143618/visa-national-no-exit-stamp-from-france-on-return-to-the-uk

Comment: "Your Sponsor will only be contacted if, through your overstay, costs occur (for which he must pay for). But since you have left, no costs will occur" do you mean if i was staying in germany, and get caught by the authorities?

Comment: correct. as you did not overstay, but left, there would be no costs occurred for your overstay (which didn't happen), therefor the sponsor would have no reason to be contacted.

Comment: Was your passport stamped by the next country you entered after leaving the Schengen area?  If so, there's your proof!

Comment: Not at all......

Answer (score 6):

The Schengen Borders Code states:

“The travel documents of non-EU nationals are systematically stamped upon entry and exit. If a travel document does not bear an entry stamp, it may be presumed that the holder does not fulfil, or no longer fulfils, the conditions of duration of a short stay. However, the non-EU-country national may provide any credible evidence of having respected the conditions relating to the duration of a short stay, such as transport tickets or proof of his/her presence outside the territory of the EU countries. On the request of a non-EU-country national, the insertion of an entry or exit stamp may be dispensed with if this insertion is liable to cause difficulties for the person. Instead, the stamp must be recorded on a separate sheet indicating the person’s name and passport number.”

Source: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/EN/legal-content/summary/schengen-borders-code.html

Keep evidence of the date you exited Schengen (eg boarding pass, proof of arrival in India etc) and you and your sponsor should not have any problems in future.

Comment: yes I have still the boarding pass, and money receip, as i went to atm in india, right after landing ( and also my coffe ticket in dubai)

Answer (score 2):

Embassy can't hurt

You mention that the German Embassy said they cannot help, however you don't specify what you asked them specifically. While I don't think they would "*backstamp*" your passport, it should be pretty easy for them to provide you with an official document stating that Kmi with passport number 1234 is in front of them in the Embassy located in India at date XYZ, despite passport 1234 not bearing an exit stamp, and they produce such document at the passport holder request.

I assume more than your allowed haven't passed since you arrived to Schengen area, so it doesn't really matter the exact day you left, as if you are in India *today* you cannot have overstayed.

While not really required (as mentioned by other answers), such document should calm your sponsor or, really, any issue in the future where the lack of exit stamp could be questioned.